# How to delay executeQuery() of jdbc preparedStatement intentionally?

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, timeout

It is mentioned in the Java API docs that Statement interface has setQueryTimeOut method. And I did use it with PreparedStatement. 
Now unfortunately I am not able to confirm that it is indeed working.
I have set it to 1s which is minimum like below:

```
pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
pstmt.setString(1, age);
pstmt.setQueryTimeout(1);
resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Query is simple Select query from a view based on age.
But Db response has become better and execution of query is getting completed within 500ms. How to intentionally delay the execution of query so that SQLException which will be thrown by setQueryTimeOut method will be caught?

Comment: Execute a query that takes a long time, connect through a network proxy that delays packets, etc?

Comment: `Statement.setQueryTimeout()` is not used for intentionally delaying the query execution; instead, it's purpose is to specify a timeout value after which the query execution is aborted (default is no timeout). _Why_ do you want to make the execution slower?

Comment: Thats correct. I want to test the timeout for the same simple query. I want to see exception being thrown after timeout.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it did work after giving a very complex query. i was able to see the exception. Is there any way to see the same for a simple query ?

Comment: Use a very short time out, or use a network proxy that delays packets.

Answer (score 0):

You can pause via TimeUnit class which is `java.util.concurrent package`.

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
```

To sleep for one second or

```
TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
```

To sleep for a minute.

Implement in this way

```
pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
pstmt.setString(1, age);
TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

On a fine note sleep method throws `InterruptedException` exception so you have to take care of that.

**Also if you don't want an overhead of** `TimeUnit` class just simply call Thead.sleep(long) in your code in below manner.

```
pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
pstmt.setString(1, age);
Thread.sleep(60);
resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

But again you have to take care of `InterruptedException` which sleep method throws.

Comment: I think OP need to delay the execution of `resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();` statement itself.

Comment: That is correct. I would like to delay executeQuery() itself so that timeout can be verified.

Comment: Oh Sorry! didn't thought about that, Can't you increase the time while calling setQueryTimeout method